# How can I plot one plane in Surface plot (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, surface

This is the figure I have with me now. There are 10 planes, but I want to plot them individually. How can I do that?

[image: figure]

Answer (score 0):

mesh(X,Y,Z) creates a mesh plot, which is a three-dimensional surface that has solid edge colors and no face colors. The function plots the values in matrix Z as heights above a grid in the x-y plane defined by X and Y. The edge colors vary according to the heights specified by Z.